# char_length not working as thought

Tags: mysql

Below is what I have

```
+++++++++++++++
+ id + myData +
+++++++++++++++
+ 1  + ABCD   +
+ 2  + ABCDD  +
+++++++++++++++
```

When I execute

```
select char_length((select myData from mytable where id = 1)) as MyLength;
```

I get result as

```
++++++++++++
+ MyLength +
++++++++++++
+  4       +
++++++++++++
```

But when I execute query,

```
select char_length((select myData from mytable) as MyLength;
```

I get error as

```
DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed.
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc039/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrapping the entire query output in `CHAR_LENGTH()`.  When applying the `WHERE id = 1` to the subquery, it returns a single row, and since you've selected a single column, you get one single string value back which `CHAR_LENGTH()` will accept as its argument.

If the subquery `select mySata from mytable` returns multiple rows, `char_length()` cannot accept it as an input.  Instead, merely apply `CHAR_LENGTH()` to `myData` in a regular `SELECT` statement to see the lengths of multiple rows.

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(myData) AS myLength FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

With `char_length((select myData from mytable))` you are passing a rowset object into the function, which `char_length` can not dealt with.

When calling functions with query results, make sure you select only one row, and only one column, so the result can be interpreted as a single value.